# Is this UPS isolated, and how?

Tags: grounding, isolation, ups

I have this UPS: [APC Smart-UPS SRT 2200VA RM 230V](https://www.apc.com/shop/uk/en/products/APC-Smart-UPS-SRT-2200VA-RM-230V/P-SRT2200RMXLI).

<sub>I am not located in the UK, but the device is intended for the European market, I am linking to the UK version of the APC website so it is in English.</sub>

This is what **I suspected** it to look inside:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSZGpS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am somewhat puzzled about its grounding/isolation. It is a dual inverter device (aka online), so I assumed that for sure the output would be galvanically isolated. (Surely at least one of the AC -> DC or the DC -> AC converters would contain a transformer, right? In the schematic I drew it explicitly.). Now, reading [this post](https://www.apc.com/us/en/faqs/FA157465/) by the manufacturer, I am not so sure.

If it is not isolated, what does that mean?

I get that in bypass mode, it is not isolated. But when running the inverters, surely it cannot connect the line? If nothing else, this would make the input plug hot!

Does it instead connect the neutral? I know the device refuses to start if neutral and line are reversed on the input. (Happens easily enough, the European Schuko plug & receptacle are not polarized!)

What about grounding? If the neutral is not passed through, and instead is indeed isolated from primary neutral, is it grounded, as drawn in my sketch? Or is it floating?

I think these questions are very relevant for safety (e.g. installation of a downstream RCD), but the [manual](https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_File_Name=SU_OM_990_5269D_EN.pdf&p_Doc_Ref=SPD_JGNY-9LPDQJ_EN&p_enDocType=User+guide) and other [documentation](https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_File_Name=KCHY-A3NDUJ_R0_EN.pdf&p_Doc_Ref=SPD_KCHY-A3NDUJ_EN&p_enDocType=Technical+Drawing) seem rather tacit...

Comment: Not sure, you can have an online UPS without being galvanically isolated.

Comment: I learned that too, hence my question :)

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because I'm pretty sure I was wrong.

Comment: I object to this question being closed. I asked about the inner workings of the device (this one specifically, but dual-inverter UPSes in general). I want to know how I can safely protect the output side, so the question is *very much about electronic design*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schneider really made this information quite difficult to find, but here it is: [Why can I measure voltage between the ground and neutral wires when my UPS is on battery?](https://www.se.com/us/en/faqs/FA156549/)

> One result of breaking the input Neutral and Hot connections when operating on battery is that you may be able to measure voltage between Neutral and Ground at the output receptacles when the UPS is on battery. This is phantom voltage which cannot damage equipment or give the smallest of electric shocks.

This implies that there is no connection between neutral and ground when the UPS is operating on battery, which means that it uses an IT earthing system. Live and neutral are floating with respect to ground. RCDs therefore will not work while the UPS is on battery.

One annoying side-effect of this is that if you have a TNS system, the outputs of the UPS will switch between TNS and IT earthing whenever the UPS switches over to battery operation.

If you need a TNS system, you have to use an isolation transformer after the UPS and create the required connection between ground and neutral on its secondary side.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Is it any different if *both* inverters are running? I.e. if power still comes from the utility, rather than the battery?

Comment: The output has to be disconnected from mains to run the DC->AC inverter, so neutral will still be disconnected from earth in that case.

Comment: I see. That is indeed unfortunate. So for a downstream RCD to work, I must ground the output. If the UPS then were to go into bypass mode, it would trigger the *upstream* RCD.

Comment: Grounding the UPS output is a very, very bad idea. If you need a downstream RCD, an isolation transformer is the only way to go with this UPS.

Comment: Exactly, realized that as well.

Comment: I haven't forgotten to accept your answer. I actually also had contacted Schneider's support, I am waiting for their response first.